# Validate endpoints in substring w/o splitting

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate (preferably with .matches()) that the part before % in for example "ookd&sr34!abc**%**blabla.h" does not begin or end with for example 'k'. 'k' must, however,  be allowed in between those endpoints (beginning to %, exclusive).

I can't use the end anchor because I don't want the end of the whole string. Also, I don't want to split the string, I want to do it all in one regex.

Possibly some kind of lookahead? I'm stuck.

Comment: Why a regex?  It seems like this would be easier done by just checking for the `k`s with `charAt()`, or taking a substring and using `startsWith()` and `endsWith()`. (In Java, `substring()` does not create a copy.)

Comment: Millimoose what did you mean by substring() does not create a copy?  Did you mean a copy of the entire string?  Or that it doesn't create a new string?  Because it sure does create a new string, which is a substring of your original..  So you have 2 strings in your string pool - your original, and your new substring.

Comment: @PenelopeTheDuck `substring` returns a new String object but internally this object points to the same underlying `char[]` as the original, just with a different offset and length.

Comment: @Ian Roberts, while this was certainly true in older versions of Java, it is no longer the case.  Now a new string is created internally each time. I believe this was introduced with Java 7 update 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
str.matches("(?!k)[^%]*(?<!k)%.*")
```

If you ignore the look-arounds this matches any sequence of characters up to the first %, then the %, then everything else. The lookahead at the start ensures the first character (if there is one) is not k and the look behind ensures that the last character before the first % (if there is one) is not k. Unlike the naive `[^k].*?[^k]%` this allows for the case where there are fewer than two characters before the %.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp `^k.*k%`.

```
matches("ookd&sr34!abc*%*blabla.h") -> false
matches("kokd&sr34!abc*k%*blabla.h") -> true
matches("kookd&sr34!abc*%*blabla.h") -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestClass {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "ookd&sr34!abc*%*blabla.h";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^k.*k%");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
    while(m.find()){
      System.out.println(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^k.*k%.*", myString));
    System.out.println(myString.matches("^k.*k%.*"));
  }
}
```

Never used the matches before, but it seems to require the .* on the end, after the % or it will return false - presumably because it evaluates the entire string and not just a part of it like the Matcher.find() method.